# Angular 4 - .filter is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this code:

```
 transform(searchData: Array<vw_WebSiteCourseSearch>, searchResultContentType: string) {
        if (searchData == undefined) {
            return;
        }

        return searchData.filter((item) => item.ContentType == searchResultContentType);
    }
```

My console prints:

```
ERROR TypeError: searchData.filter is not a function
at FilterCountPipe.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/Common/pipes/filterCount.pipe.ts.FilterCountPipe.transform (filterCount.pipe.ts:19)
```

I tried to add import from rxjs/add/operator/filter, but it didn't solved it.
Any ideas on how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: For what I see, `searchData` is an array (or you intend it to be), so you dont' have to import anything. The problem, I think, is that `searchData` is not an array, hence the error.

Comment: Look what `searchData` truly is, maybe by logging it to the console

Comment: Can you put a Chrome breakpoint on your if statement ? Then check the contents of `searchData`, as it will probably be null as Oscar pointed out.

Comment: I declared it as an array in the first line,
searchData: Array<vw_webSiteCourseSearch>

Comment: That is not a compiler error, or is it? If not, it does not matter what you declared it as, the question is what value it has at run time.

Comment: I think that you are right, it seems like somehow it jumps over my condition to check if it is undefined, and trying to filter a null array

Comment: `if (searchData=== undefined || searchData=== null)` is usually the technique we use for this scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should `searchData` be null (or undefined), you should get an error like

```
TypeError: cannot read property filter of null  // or undefined
```

Like @OscarPaz thought, `filter is not a function` is thrown because the received `searchData` is not an array (yet still defined and not null).

Comment: How come it is not an array, if it is defined as one?

Comment: @AaYy: Do you know all instances in which this function is called? If any call passes in an `any` value, or if the call is from some external JS you have no guarantees on the actual type of the value.

Comment: Exactly. You have declared that `searchData` is expected to be an `Array` but it doesn't mean that you are actually passing an array when invoking `transform`.

Answer (score -2):

Just change `Array` to `array`. the first one is an object and the second is an array. you can have more informations about ``filter` here [1].

[1] : https://alligator.io/js/filter-array-method/

Comment: (TS) Cannot find name 'array'